# I just downloaded Ruby 2.0.0 using RubyInstaller, but Ruby -v still says I'm running 1.9.3. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.0, rubyinstaller

I just downloaded Ruby 2.0.0 using RubyInstaller, but Ruby -v still says I'm running 1.9.3. What am I doing wrong?

I am running Windows 7 (which I know is not ideal, but is what I'm currently stuck with), and I have successfully run Ruby in the past.

Thanks!

Comment: What version manager are you using? RVM, RBENV, nothing? Essentially your problem is 1.9.3 is being found before 2.0. Could be just your Path.

Comment: Thanks, how do I see what my path is/change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a combination of several answers here, including:

- Uninstalling old versions of Ruby and reinstalling version 2.0.0
- Update the path Environment variable to the new path
- *Restart the computer* (I think this is what I was missing the whole time)

Thanks to everyone who helped!

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the `PATH` environment variable. Most likely it contains path to `ruby1.9.3/bin`. Change it to point to `ruby2.0/bin`

Comment: Thanks. This might be a stupid question, but where do I find the Path environment variable to check out?

Comment: @jackerman09 open a command prompt and enter the command "set PATH" (without the quotes). This will print the contents of the PATH environment variable.

Comment: @Andy, thanks. I see Ruby in the path "C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin, is this what I need to change? If so, how do I change it? Thanks again

Comment: @jackerman09 Yes, that is what you need to change. If you right click Computer, select Properties, then go to Advanced Settings (I think, it's one of the links on the left), then click on Environment Variables.

Comment: Hey @Andy, I actually found this just before you responded, but changing it to 2.0 or to 2.0.0 don't change what is output when I run ruby -v. Any other possibilities you can think of? Also, I have User variables and System variables, and right now the current path only exists as a User variable. Is that a problem? Thanks again

Comment: @jackerman09 Have you restarted the console after changing the variable ?

Comment: @roody, no I have not, but I'll try that. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

first uninstall all your rubies and then install ruby 2.0, you cannot maintain two versions of ruby without RVM or RBENV.